# Plot of a R -> R^2 fuction

Tags: plotting

I have an algorithm that when you insert the parameter `B`, the function gives a solution `{x,y}`.

How can I plot that? I tried `Plot[Solution[B], {b, 0, 3}]` but it gives me a 2D graph!

Thanks

Comment: Please specify `Solution[...]`.

Comment: Take a look at [`ParametricPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html).

Comment: We need more info before we can help.

Answer (score 2):

Proceed with `ParametricPlot`, e.g.:

```
solution[x_] := {Sin[x], Cos[x]}
ParametricPlot[solution[b], {b, 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

[image: simple example for ParametricPlot]